# interval spacing on matlab

Tags: matlab, ggplot2

Hi I'm new to matlab and programming in general and I was wondering if anyone could tell me whats wrong with my code.

These were my instructions and values

> Complete the implementation of the dampedOsc function, which evaluates and plots a graph showing the function y=e-0.8xcos 3x at a
>   set of points spaced at intervals of 0.1 and ranging from 0 to 3π.
>
> The curve should be displayed using a magenta dotted line with
>   'pentagram' markers.

and my code:

```
function y = dampedOsc(x)

    fplot(@(x) (exp(-0.8*x)*cos(3*x)),[0 3*pi()],'mp:')   
end
```

All tests passed except this one:

Test 1 (Test that function has been plotted):
Actual value does not have correct size:

```
expectedSize =

     1    95


actualSize =

     1    98

Test failed.
```

I honestly have no idea whats gone wrong, I thought it was because of the lack 
of point spaced intervals but I have no idea how to input it.

Comment: That is because of the interval, as in your instructions it says it should be done with a interval of 0.1, however in your code you are letting the function (`fplot`) choose for you. To avoid that, you likely need to use the function `plot`, and generate the `y` values by evaluating the desired `x` in the function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Thats the part that I'm not sure how to do, I've input function y = dampedOsc(x)

    fplot(@(x) (exp(1)^(-0.8*x)*cos(3*x)),[0:0.1:3*pi()],'mp:')   
                                                                                                               
end   
                                                                                                                
but the actualSize output is now [1    54]  I have tried x=0:0.1:3*pi() but it results in an error and wont function at all, do you know if its where I'm putting it?                   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting question, so I'll give it a stab.  I would probably do something like this.

```
function z = dampedOsc(x)
    if isvector(x) == 0
        return
    else
        z = zeros(1,length(x));
        for n = 1 : length(x)
            y = exp(-0.8 .* x(n)) .* cos(3 .* x(n));
            z(1,n) = y;
        end
    end
    z
end
```

Then, calling that `dampedOsc` function from another script, should give the figure.

```
plot([0 : 0.1 : (3*pi)],dampedOsc(x),'mp:')
```

I don't have MATLAB in front of me right now, but I think this should work.  If it doesn't, I can fix it.  Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hi thankyou for your reply, I've input function y = dampedOsc(x) fplot(@(x) (exp(1)^(-0.8*x)*cos(3*x)),[0:0.1:3*pi()],'mp:') end but the actualSize output is now [1 54] I have tried x=0:0.1:3*pi() but it results in an error and wont function at all, do you know if its where I'm putting it? I've also tried plot([0 : 0.1 : (3*pi)],dampedOsc(x),'mp:') Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "actualSize output"?  Do you mean the length of the vector?  If you try "x=0:0.1:3*pi()" don't use parentheses for what looks like you are creating an instance of `pi`.  You do not have to do that in MATLAB, and that may contribute to the error.  Just use `pi`.  The interval would be: `x = [0 : 0.1 : (3*pi)];` which says x is a row vector containing values from zero to three pi with 0.1 between each value.

Comment: thanks, I gave this function y = dampedOsc(x)

    fplot(@(x) (exp(1)^(-0.8*x)*cos(3*x)),[0:0.1:3*pi()],'mp:')   
   
end                                                                                                                  and this function y = dampedOsc(x)

    fplot(@(x) (exp(1)^(-0.8*x)*cos(3*x)),[0:0.1:3*pi];'mp:')   
   
end                                                                                                                     a go but I'm still scoring 3/4 and the transcript output's expected (actualSize) is the one that is failing.